# What's the use case for the MonadReader instance for (->) r

Tags: haskell

I find the `MonadReader` instance for `(->) r` difficult to understand.
Someone from irc mentions one use case for extending some polymorphic functions found in other people's package. I couldn't recall exactly what he meant. Here's an example that relates to what he said but I don't see the point. Could anyone give another example on the usecase of `MonadReader` for `(->) r`

```
func :: (Show a, MonadReader Int m) => Bool -> m a
func b = case b of
  True -> do
    i <- ask
    show i
  False -> "error"

main :: IO ()
main = print $ func True 5
```

Comment: `(->) r` is "the same" as `Reader r` (just without the `newtype` wrapper), so it's the most basic example, essentially the defining example, of the `MonadReader` class. Not sure why you need a specific use case.

Comment: @RobinZigmond For someone new to Haskell, the notion that a function that takes `r` as input is of the `MonadReader` typeclass seems really bizzare. I think it's legit to see how anyone actually uses the fact that `(->) r` is a `MonadReader`

Comment: Many instances exist in Haskell because they *can* exist. You may not have a particular use in mind for using `(->) r` directly instead of `Reader`, but that doesn't mean you should *prevent* `(->) r` from being used when it *could* be.

Comment: I'd be the first to admit that there is lots about Haskell that seems bizarre when new to it. And it's perfectly understandable to be confused about what a typeclass like `MonadReader` is for. But your specific question still strikes me as odd, because the way (at least the normal one) to understand what this type class does is to first take the most basic instance, and understand how it allows you (read only) access to a value of type `r`. `MonadReader` basically only exists in order to generalise this "function Monad", so it seems strange to me to ask the question the way you did.

Comment: @chepner: It is a bit curious though—I use the Functor and Applicative instances of `(->) r` all the time in pointfree code, I just almost never make use of the fact that the question is asking about, that it’s an instance of `MonadReader`. The only time I have, it was when I had a function `doThing :: MonadReader Env m => m Result -> …` and I wanted to call it in test code as `doThing (\ env -> …)` without any `newtype` fanfare nor the rest of the stack in question. Which, to me, is what `mtl` is really for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it was intended to have a use case separate from the `Reader` monad.

Here's some of the history...

The inspiration for the `transformers` library was the set of lecture notes [Functional Programming with Overloading and Higher-Order Polymorphism](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/springschool.html) (Mark P. Jones, 1995).  In these notes, several named monads (`State`, `Id`, `List`, `Maybe`, `Error`, and `Writer`) were discussed.  For example, the `Writer` monad type and its instance were defined as:

```
data Writer a = Result String a
instance Monad Writer where
    result x            = Result "" x
    Result s x ‘bind‘ f = Result (s ++ s’) y
                          where Result s’ y = f x
```

The reader monad was also discussed, but it wasn't defined as a separate type.  Rather a `Read` type alias was used together with a `Monad` instance defined directly in terms of the partially applied function type `(->) r`:

```
type Read r = (r ->)
instance Monad (r->) where
    result x = \r -> x
    x ‘bind‘ f = \r -> f (x r) r
```

I don't actually know if these type-level "sections" `(r ->)` were valid Haskell syntax at the time.  Anyway, it's not valid syntax with modern GHC versions, but that's how it appeared in the notes.

The first version of the `transformers` library authored by Andy Gill -- or at least the first that I was able to find, and it was actually still part of the `base` library at that time -- was checked into Git in June, 2001.  It introduced the `MonadReader` class and the newtype wrapped `Reader`:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }
```

together with its `Functor`, `Monad`, `MonadFix`, and `MonadReader` instances.  (No `Applicative` -- that hadn't been invented yet.)  It **also included** a set of instances for `(->) r` with the comment:

> The partially applied function type is a simple reader monad

So, I think the original formulation in the lecture notes led Andy to include these instances for `(->) r`, even though he *also* introduced a dedicated `Reader` newtype for consistency with the other monads in the `transformers` library.

Anyway, that's the history.  As for use cases, I can only think of one serious one, though perhaps it isn't that compelling.  The `lens` library is designed to interface well with `MonadState` and `MonadReader` to access complex states/contexts.  Because functions like:

```
view :: MonadReader s m => Getting a s a -> m a 
preview :: MonadReader s m => Getting (First a) s a -> m (Maybe a) 
review :: MonadReader b m => AReview t b -> m t
```

are defined in terms of the `MonadReader` instance, they can be used both in a traditional `Reader` context:

```
do ...
   outdir <- view (config.directories.output)
   ...
```

and in a plain function context:

```
map (view (links.parent.left)) treeStructure
```

Again, not necessarily a *compelling* use case, but it's a use case.

Comment: I'm also not sure if `Reader` serves any purpose other than to give a more intuitive "face" to `(->)`. I'm not aware of any typeclasses where `Reader r` and `(->) r` have different instances.

Answer (score 2):

The point is to make it easier to combine functions that all take the same environment.

Consider the type `a -> Env -> b`, where `Env` is some data type that contains all your "global" variables. Let's say you wanted to compose two such functions. You can't just write `h = f2 . f1`, because `f1`'s return type `Env -> b` doesn't match `f2`'s argument type `b`.

```
f1 :: a -> Env -> b  -- a -> ((->) Env b)
f2 :: b -> Env -> c  -- b -> ((->) Env c)

h :: a -> Env -> c
h x e = let v = f1 x e
        in f2 v e
```

Because there is an applicable `MonadReader` instance for the monad `(->) Env`, you can write this as

```
-- The class, ignoring default method implementations, is
-- class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
--   ask :: m r
--   local :: (r -> r) -> m a -> m a
--   reader :: (r -> a) -> m a
--
-- The functional dependency means that if you try to use (->) Env
-- as the monad, Env is forced to be the type bound to r.
--
-- instance MonadReader r ((->) r) where 
--    ask = id
--    local f m = m . f
--    reader = id

h :: MonadReader Env m => a -> m c
h x = do
    v <- f1 x
    f2 v
-- h x = f1 x >>= f2
```

without explicit reference to the environment, which `h` doesn't
care about; only `f1` and `f2` do.

More simply, you can use the Kleisli composition operator to define the same function.

```
import Control.Monad

h :: MonadReader Env m => a -> m c
h = f1 >=> f2
```

---

In your example, `ask` is simply how you get access to the environment from inside the body of the function, rather than having it as a preexisting argument to the function. Without the `MonadReader` instance, you would write something like

```
func :: Show a => Bool -> Int -> a  -- m ~ (->) Int
func b i = case b of
            True -> show i
            False -> error "nope"
```

The definition of `main` stays the same. However, `(->) Int` isn't the *only* type that has a `MonadReader` instance; there could be a more complicated monad stack
that you are using elsewhere, which the more general type `(Show a, MonadReader Int m) => Bool -> m a` allows you to use instead of "just" `(->) Int`.